# Jquery Marquee Usage by Remy Sharp

Tags: jquery, marquee

I am using Remy Sharps Marquee Plugin. I am trying to figure out if it is possible to start/stop the marquee when a user presses a button. There is some demo code on the page, but that is within the plugin itself.

http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning marque object to a global variable and then trigger start/stop on it.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.marquee.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    var marque;
    $(function () {

        marque= $('div.demo marquee').marquee('pointer');
    });

    function startmqr() {
        $(marque).trigger('start');
    }
    function stop() {
        $(marque).trigger('stop');
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="demo">
        <h2>
            Vanilla</h2>
        <pre><code>&lt;marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="1" direction="left" width="350"&gt;</code></pre>
        <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="2" width="350"><p>START Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet END</p></marquee>
    </div>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="start" onclick="startmqr()" />
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="stop" onclick="stop()" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards